# mypy の `type(self) is type(other)` で other の型が絞り込みされない

Tags: python, mypy

## 質問

既存の Python コードに mypy を導入しようとしています。あるクラスに以下のような型注釈を付けました。

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.foo = "bar"

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if type(self) is type(other):
            return self.foo == other.foo
        return super().__eq__(other)
```

このコードを mypy に入力すると、`other.foo` の箇所でエラーが起きます。

```
$ mypy test.py
test.py:7: error: "object" has no attribute "foo"  [attr-defined]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

`if type(self) is type(other):` で `other` の型が `typing.Self` に絞り込まれることを期待していたのですが、実際には `object` 型のままとなり、`foo` 属性が存在しないというエラーになっています。なぜ型絞り込みが機能しないのでしょうか？

### 環境

- Python 3.11.6
- mypy 1.8.0 (compiled: no)

### やったこと

- `type(self) is type(other)` を `isinstance(other, type(self))` に書き換えるとエラーが出なくなりますが、既存コードから動作が変化してしまいます。

### 背景

問題のコードは、データクラス `A` に `__eq__` 特殊メソッドを実装することを意図しています。期待動作としては、オブジェクト同士を `==` 演算子で比較したとき、双方の型が `A` で、かつ `.foo` 属性が一致しているときに `true`、それ以外の場合は `false` を返します。

本来、型注釈が使える環境でデータクラスを実装する際は、dataclasses などのモジュールを使うほうが楽です。しかし、今回は型注釈の無い既存コードが対象ですので、まずは既存コードをなるべく変えずに型注釈を追加する方針で進めています。

Comment: 任意のクラスのインスタンスということであれば、`other` に対する annotation は不要でしょう。`def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:`

Comment: annotation を付けない場合 `Any` 型となり、型チェックが一切行われません。一方で `object` 型にすると、すべての型に対して有効な操作しか受け付けなくなります。https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dynamic_typing.html#any-vs-object この数行程度のコードに型チェックが必要かと言われると、確かに不要かもしれません、、、

Comment: > オブジェクト同士を == 演算子で比較したとき、双方の型が A で、かつ .foo 属性が一致しているときに true、それ以外の場合は false を返します
 ということは、A型を継承した子クラスを作ることはこの時点では考えていないということでしょうか? だとすると今度は、isinstance(other, type(self))に「既存コードから動作が変化してしまいます」と言っているのがどういう意味か分からなくなります

Comment: 親クラスと子クラスを比較した場合、比較結果が常に `False` となることを意図しています。また、同じ子クラス同士で比較した場合、`.foo` 属性が一致していれば `True` となることを想定しています（子クラスで `__eq__` をオーバーライドせずに使うことはあまり無い気もしますが）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html

Type narrowing が起きるのは`type(foo) is 型`と書いた時です

`type(foo) is type(bar)`という形で書いたら、一方が決定的であってもType narrowingは起きません。`type(foo) is type(bar)`と書いたら通ると思ったのがただの勘違い、としか言いようがない気はします

例えば、決定的であることがより明らかな

```py
def hoge(x:object):
    if type(x) is type(0):
        x.bit_count()
```

でもmypyの型チェックは通りませんでした

（質問のコードの意図がちょっとよく分からなかったので事実の指摘だけ）

---

追記

背景に書かれたこと**だけ**見るなら（ただしコメントしたように、別の箇所の意味が分からなくなっています）

```py
    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        if type(other) is A:
            return self.foo == other.foo
        return False
```

でよいです。**継承を考えないなら**、`A`と比較すればよく、Aでない時は`super().__eq__(other)`がFalseになるのは自明なので単純にFalseを返すべきです。

otherの型注釈は`Any`が妥当だと思います
型注釈に`object`を書くのは「私はobjectに用意された属性しか使うつもりがありません」と主張したい時です。逆に型注釈に`object`を書かれていたらコードを読む側は「objectに用意された属性だけ使うんだな」と感じるはずです

---

追記

```py
if type(self) is other.__class__:
    return self.foo == other.foo
```

や

```py
if type(other) is self.__class__:
    return self.foo == other.foo
```

だとmypyのチェックが通る様です。なぜかは説明できないですが

Comment: 質問に、コードの意図などの背景情報を追記しました。

Comment: その通りでした、筆が滑りました(訂正済み)